# try to deploy an Application written for Tomcat 4.4 J2SE 1.4 with Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, compilation, compatibility

I try to deploy an App that i only have in an very old version, tomcat 4.4. this software does use jdk 1.4.2_16. this is very old.
since i can't get an more recent version of the webapp, i still want to use this webapp (jsp-files) in tomcat9 with JRE 1.8.0_201.
so far so good, i installed a tomcat9 server and first tried to deploy the application to webapps folder, but trying to access the application via web browser fails ultimately since the syntax has changed a lot since jdk 1.4 on java 8 or even OpenJDK 11.
my idea now was to download the old jdk 1.4.2_16, use the javac compiler for compiling the .jspp files in order to be compatible (producing compatible bytecode through already compiled bytecode cause of the old jdk).
so i added in my web.xml these entries:

```
        <init-param>
        <param-name>compiler</param-name>
        <param-value>javac1.4</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>executable</param-name>
        <param-value>C:/j2sdk1.4.2_16/bin/javac.exe</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.4</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.4</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
```

however, this creates a lot of errors after deploying the software and accessing it via web browser. as i see so far he indeed *does* use the javac compiler of jdk 1.4.2_16. but the errors that appear (HTTP Status 500 - internal server error) does not make any sense to me.

The errors were like

```
An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\x44\org\apache\jsp\web\onefile.java]
    [javac] C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/work/Catalina/localhost/x44/org/apache/jsp/web/onefile.java:84: <identifier> expected
    [javac]   private static java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long> _jspx_dependants;
    [javac]                               ^


An error occurred at line: [-1] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\x44\org\apache\jsp\web\onefile.java]
    [javac] C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 9.0/work/Catalina/localhost/x44/org/apache/jsp/web/onefile.java:87: '(' or '[' expected
    [javac]     _jspx_dependants = new java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Long>(1);
```

i really dont understand how this error occurs. the javac compiler of 1.4 should not have any problems with his own generated code. and, even if it is the jre 1.8 that complains about it. isn't java 8 bytecompatible to older java versions? so i don't get the point why this doesn't work.

if anyone have an idea, please let me now. i *do* know that you shouldn't use old JDKs, i *do* know that outdated software is best left alone but still, even in theory, i'm interested how much room is there for compatibility.

Comment: I think you will be better served by focusing on trying to get the JSP pages working when compiled with the default compiler. Ask for help with the problems you get with that instead.

Comment: Why not run a JRE 1.4 compatible tomcat version? [5.5.36 should fit](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)

Comment: Please respect your readers enough to use proper case, full sentences, etc. when posting here. This site is meant to be more like Wikipedia, less like a casual chat room.

Comment: I'd take a look at the [Tomcat 9 docs for JSP configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration) - you're not using what you expect as there is no `executable` config parameter, and your `compiler` parameter is wrong.  It's unclear what the JSP compiler will do with bad parameters.

Comment: well at first let me tell you that i try to do my best in talking english. my english is not the best, i know. i apologize for writing in bad language.
however, what i didnt understand was the reference of the tomcat documentation "compiler - Which compiler Ant should use to compile JSP pages. The valid values for this are the same as for the compiler attribute of Ant's javac task. ""
there is an option for compiler that is called "extJavac". i thought this might be useful but it didnt changed anything. if i change the path variable it certainly uses the javac executable of tomcat.

Comment: but i do understand that the executable config parameter does not work. i was just too focused on the javac task arguments and had the idea that maybe tomcat is simply using all tags from web.xml with their names and values for compiling with javac (crazy idea, i know). but i still doesn't get what extJavaC means then. and there is this ominous "fork - Have Ant fork JSP page compiles so they are performed in a separate JVM from Tomcat? true or false, default true.". i thought it uses the executable i defined then. guess i should give up and try fix the jsp files

Answer (score 2):

Tomcat 9 will generate different Java code from a JSP than Tomcat 4.4 would. And Tomcat 9 will generate for the JDK that it requires as minimal match - so you'll be out of luck with compiling the Tomcat 8 code with an old JDK compiler. Among it, obviously: Generics. Where Java 1.4 knew of `Map`, newer versions know of `Map<String,Long>`.

JSPs are nothing else than input for a compiler that generates Java Servlets from the JSP, and in turn hands it to the Java compiler in question.

If your code is *only* made up of JSPs, you're better off fixing the JSPs. Otherwise, consider recompiling the whole application: You're now also on a newer servlet specification and might miss some required things. I'm not 100% confident that they're all truly binary backward-compatible.

[Tomcat 9 uses](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html):

- [Servlet spec version 4](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/)
- [JSP spec version 2.3](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/pages/2.3/)
- [Java 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_8) or later

Comment: thanks for your reply, i guess you're right with that. besides, it seems to be more work trying to deliberately force tomcat9 to support some old jsp-files as to simply adapt the jsp files. i already spent hours for making tomcat supporting it. i guess if i tried to adapt the old jsp files i would be done by now or so.